# ignore signals in child processes

Tags: linux, signals, kill

I am sending a `SIGUSR1` to PID=99, which has a signal handler in place to process it.

PID=99 calls `fork` then `exec` on a long-running command, which gets PID=100. Since the child does not inherit the signal handler, SIGUSR1 is interpreted as a `KILL`.

Is there a way to limit `kill` to send to only the parent process? I am aware that I can use `SIGIGNORE` in the child, but I am in a production environment which would entail modifying many calls to `exec`.

Comment: What does it mean to "call `exec` on a long-running command, which gets [a new PID]"?  The `exec(3)` family of functions replace the _current_ process image with a new one, and PID remains unchanged.

Comment: good catch. I was being loose with language and forgetting that, unfortunately, tclsh actually forks a subprocess when you call a bare `exec`. so, I guess I would modify this question to cover `fork; exec`.

Comment: `SIGUSR1` is not interpreted as `KILL`, but the default response is termination.  How are you invoking `kill`?  By default, the signal should not be sent to the child unless you are sending the signal to all members of the process group.

Comment: I have n different processes `./p -someargs`, each of which calls `fork` and `exec` (really just [exec hostname] in tcl). Each `p` registers a signal handler for `USR1`. A daemon, elsewhere, issues a `pkill -f -USR1 'p -someargs`, which just returns a list of pids for every p (ie not any of the children). While the parent is doing work, I get failures along the line of (child process killed: unhandled sigusr1). This indicates to me that the children are getting the signal.